# MS Project Server - How to block/interrupt save and publishd event on closed project

Tags: csom, sharepoint-2016, ms-project-server-2016

As in title, how to do it using csom to check for eg. boolean custom field 'Project closed' is set as true and lock project for editing. 
I think do it on project event, but how?
I've checked that on click save button first triggered method is OnUpdating() than OnSaved(). 
 I've try there to check CF value and return before hit on base.OnUpdating() but it didn't help.